# How to recursively ask for input, and return a list

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, io

I've been trying many different ways to do this in Haskell, and I can't for the life of me figure this out.

I want to get a list of names from the user, and if I know the length of the list (let's assume that is n), I want to prompt the user n times and ask for the i th item at the i'th time.

So far, I have this:

```
getinput a b
| a == b = []
| otherwise = input:getinput (a+1) b
where input = do
  a <- getLine
  return a
```

but I keep getting errors.

Strongly appreciate any help!

Comment: What type of error are you getting?

Comment: I got an error saying that ghci could not print the returned value correctly. That said, I guess that the printing wasn't the real problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem with your code

- The return type of `input` is `IO String` so you just can not append it to a list.
- Similarly the return type of `getinput (a+1) b` is `IO [String]` and not just `[String]`.

Here I have corrected your code

```
getinput a b | a == b = return []
             | otherwise = do
                    i <- getLine
                    rest <- getinput (a+1) b
                    return (i:rest)
```

A better and more haskellish way

```
getinput2 n = sequence $ replicate n getLine
```

Comment: Or `replicateM n getLine`.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I didn't have the faintest idea that you could do that in 1 line! Could you please tell me what sequence and replicate does in this case?
Again, thanks so very much to Satvik, and dave4420 as well.

Comment: Your haskellish code is more elegant, but OP's code isn't wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Satvik had a good answer, but your code is also 100% correct.

You **can** append an `IO String` to the beginning of a list, as long as all elements are of the same type -- so you end up with something that has the type `[IO String]`

All you need to do, with the code you've written, is apply it with `sequence` -- for example:

```
sequence $ getinput 0 4
```

Comment: Thanks so much, amindfv. Again, my mind is blown by how elegant Haskell can be!